# How to draw a radar scanning animation in osmdroid

Tags: osmdroid

I use polygon and set its fillpaint with RadialGradient,but it doesn't work!

```
val polygon = Polygon()
val pp = polygon.fillPaint
val xx = mapView.projection.toPixels(pointCenter, null).x
val yy = mapView.projection.toPixels(pointCenter, null).y
pp.shader = RadialGradient(xx.toFloat(), yy.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)

polygon.points = points
mapView.overlayManager.add(polygon)
```

Comment: I fix this problem, you should set pp.color equal any color, then your shader will appear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.